# chevals-vapeur vs. chevaux-vapeurs ?

Tags: unités

Ayant été confronté, il y a de cela fort longtemps, à la notion de cheval-vapeur, je me suis mis à douter sur son utilisation. L’usage coutumier est de parler de cheval et de chevaux pour exprimer une puissance. La locution exacte agréée est le cheval-vapeur. Étant donné qu’il s’agit là d’une unité, j’ai souvenir, en classe de physique, que nous parlions alors de chevals-vapeur au pluriel. J’ai été alors stupéfait de constater que cheval peut dans de rare cas s’écrire chevals au pluriel. Je peine à trouver sur la toile une confirmation de ce souvenir.

Est-ce que quelqu’un saurait m’aiguiller sur cette étrange utilisation du mot cheval ?

Comment: Et pourtant tous les dictionnaires en ligne donne le pluriel. https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/cheval-vapeur ¶ https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cheval-vapeur  etc.

Comment: Un article assez détaillé sur le sujet : https://www.antidote.info/fr/blogue/enquetes/la-legende-des-chevals mais qui confirme que le pluriel est chevaux dans tous les cas.

Comment: https://uel.unisciel.fr/physique/outils_nancy/outils_nancy_ch02/co/apprendre_07.html 
 précise les conventions pour le pluriel des unités utilisées en physique. On y voit notamment que le quintal (100 kg) devient quintaux au pluriel. Autres règles contre-intuitive sur les unités : celles qui proviennent du nom de leur inventeur s'écrivent tout de même en minuscule et avec un 's' au pluriel : des newtons, des joules, des pascals. Et on considère que c'est un pluriel pour un nombre égal ou supérieur à 2. Donc 1,999 newton, mais 2,001 newtons : https://aviatechno.net/unites/uniregles.php

Answer (score 4):

Ta mémoire te joue des tours, <s>chevals-vapeur</s> est une écriture erronée et la seule forme en usage au pluriel est *chevaux-vapeur*.

Tout le monde sait qu'il faut dire *chevaux* quand il y a plusieurs *chevals* ! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Même si le trait d’union pourrait laisser penser qu’il devrait y avoir une unité lexicale, on dit bien « chevaux-vapeur ».

> Il faut environ 3 chevaux-vapeur pour une paire de meules qui moud 15 à 16 hectolitres de blé par 24 heures. — (Edmond Nivoit, Notions élémentaires sur l’industrie dans le département des Ardennes, E. Jolly, Charleville, 1869, page 113)